# How to define angular routes for children pages with query params in app-routing.module.ts?

Tags: angular, routes

```
const routes: Routes = [   { path: '', component: DraftAnalysisHomeComponent },   { path: 'nfldraftanalysis', component: DraftAnalysisHomeComponent },   {
    path: 'nfldraftanalysis/averagegrades',
    component: AverageGradeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '?year=:year&teamname=:team',
        component: AverageGradeDetailsComponent,
      },
    ],   },   {
    path: 'nfldraftanalysis/averagegradeswithsteal',
    component: AverageGradeWithStealComponent,   },   { path: 'nfldraftanalysis/about', component: AboutComponent },   { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }, ]
```

When the route is navigated to "http://localhost:4200/nfldraftanalysis/averagegrades?year=:year&teamname=:team", it doesn't pick up the child component but it renders the parent component view. How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As apposed to `Url parameters` which should be registered by `RouteModule`, `Query parameters` should not.